# React 18.2 meta tags are not rendering into the index.html

Tags: reactjs, npm

I created a project and I try to get the meta tags works dynamically for all the pages.

My setup is basic: **publice** and **src** folders.

in public I have the index.html and the script folder for the dynamic-meta-tags.js file:

index.html

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/logo/cvlanes-logo.png" />
  
  <!-- manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/ -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />

  <script src="scripts/dynamic-meta-tags.js"></script>
  <!-- React components -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Wow dependencies -->
  <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom Shapes -->
  <link href="css/custom-shapes.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Fontawesome -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/brands.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/regular.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/solid.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div id="dynamic-meta-tags"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

dynamic-meta-tags.js

```
const ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");

const metaTags = window.dynamicMetaTags || {};

const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
const helmetHTML = helmet.title.toString() + helmet.meta.toString();

metaTags.title = helmet.title.toString();
metaTags.metaHTML = helmetHTML;

window.dynamicMetaTags = metaTags;

// Render the dynamic meta tags to a string
const metaTagsString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
  React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, helmet.title.toComponent(), helmet.meta.toComponent())
);

document.getElementById("dynamic-meta-tags").innerHTML = metaTagsString;
```

then I have the App.js to produce the meta tags and paths:

```
import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { useRoutes, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

import Home from './pages/Home';
import Portfolio from './pages/Portfolio';
import Jobseeking from './portfolio/Jobseeking';
import Collaboration from './portfolio/Collaboration';
import Blog from './pages/Blog';
import Blog01 from './blogs/Blog01';
import Blog02 from './blogs/Blog02';
import Blog03 from './blogs/Blog03';
import Blog04 from './blogs/Blog04';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: '/portfolio',
    element: <Portfolio />
  },
  {
    path: '/portfolio/jobseeking',
    element: <Jobseeking />
  },
  {
    path: '/portfolio/collaboration',
    element: <Collaboration />
  },
  {
    path: '/blog',
    element: <Blog />
  },
  {
    path: '/blogs/circle-of-rhythm',
    element: <Blog01 />
  },
  {
    path: '/blogs/ios-notifications',
    element: <Blog02 />
  },
  {
    path: '/blogs/premitive-human',
    element: <Blog03 />
  },
  {
    path: '/blogs/claude-ai',
    element: <Blog04 />
  }
];

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  const getMetaTags = (pathname) => {
    const publicUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

    switch (location.pathname) {
      case "/":
        return {
          title: "Landing Page",
          description: "Professional Product Designer",
          ogType: "website",
          ogImage: `${publicUrl}/img/covers/blog-default-image.jpg`,
          ogImageWidth: "1200",
          ogImageHeight: "630",
          twitterCreator: "Ali Zuhairi",
          twitterCard: "summary",
        };
      case "/portfolio":
        return {
          title: "Portfolio",
          description: "Where Magic Happens",
          ogType: "Portfolio Page",
          ogImage: `${publicUrl}/img/covers/portfolio-default-image.jpg`,
          ogImageWidth: "1200",
          ogImageHeight: "630",
          imageAlt: "Portfolio",
        };
      case "/blog":
        return {
          title: "Blog",
          description: "To Blog... or not to Blog",
          ogType: "Page",
          ogImage: `${publicUrl}/img/covers/blog-default-image.jpg`,
          ogImageWidth: "1200",
          ogImageHeight: "630",
          imageAlt: "Blog",
        };
      case "/portfolio/jobseeking":
        return {
          title: "Job Seeking Application",
          description: "Job Seeking Application",
          ogType: "Portfolio",
          ogImage: `${publicUrl}/img/covers/portfolio-jobseeking-default-image.jpg`,
          ogImageWidth: "1200",
          ogImageHeight: "630",
          imageAlt: "Job Seeking Application",
        };

      case "/portfolio/collaboration":
        return {
          title: "Collaboration Workflow Platform",
          description: "Collaboration Workflow Platform",
          ogType: "Portfolio",
          ogImage: `${publicUrl}/img/covers/portfolio-collaboration-default-image.jpg`,
          ogImageWidth: "1200",
          ogImageHeight: "630",
          imageAlt: "Collaboration Workflow Platform",
        };

      case "/blogs/circle-of-rhythm":
        return {
          title: "Daily Rhythm",
          description: "Circle of Daily Rhythm",
          ogType: "article",
          ogImage: `${publicUrl}/img/covers/blogs-circle-of-rhythm-default-image.jpg`,
          ogImageWidth: "1200",
          ogImageHeight: "630",
          imageAlt: "Daily Rhythm",
        };

      case "/blogs/ios-notifications":
        return {
          title: "Notifications on iOS",
          description: "How to get notifications on iOS with personal focus on?",
          ogType: "article",
          ogImage: `${publicUrl}/img/covers/blogs-ios-notifications-default-image.jpg`,
          ogImageWidth: "1200",
          ogImageHeight: "630",
          imageAlt: "Notifications on iOS",
        };

      case "/blogs/premitive-human":
        return {
          title: "Embracing the Era of AI",
          description: "Humanity's Journey to Unparalleled Sophistication",
          ogType: "article",
          ogImage: `${publicUrl}/img/covers/blogs-premitive-human-default-image.jpg`,
          ogImageWidth: "1200",
          ogImageHeight: "630",
          imageAlt: "Era of AI",
        };

      default:
        return {};
    }
  };

  const metaTags = getMetaTags(location.pathname);
  const element = useRoutes(routes);

  return (
    <HelmetProvider>
      <Helmet>
        <title>{metaTags.title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={metaTags.description} />
        {metaTags.ogType && (
          <>
            <meta name="title" property="og:title" content={metaTags.title} />
            <meta name="description" property="og:description" content={metaTags.description} />
            <meta name="author" content="Ali Zuhairi"></meta>
            <meta name="type" property="og:type" content={metaTags.ogType} />
            <meta name="url" property="og:url" content={metaTags.ogUrl} />
            <meta name="image" property="og:image" content={metaTags.ogImage} />
            <meta property="og:image:width" content={metaTags.ogImageWidth} />
            <meta property="og:image:height" content={metaTags.ogImageHeight} />
            <meta name="twitter:title" content={metaTags.title} />
            <meta name="twitter:description" content={metaTags.description} />
            <meta name="twitter:image" content={metaTags.ogImage} />
            <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
          </>
        )}
        {metaTags.imageAlt && (
          <meta property="image:alt" content={metaTags.imageAlt} />
        )}
      </Helmet>
      {element} {/* Render the element without wrapping it in <BrowserRouter> */}
    </HelmetProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And finally, I have my index.js which I wrap my application:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import App from './App';

import './index.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HelmetProvider> {/* Wrap the entire app with HelmetProvider */}
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </HelmetProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

The problem is that the tags are not rendered.
I have tried to add the tags into the files but still no success:

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';

const PortfolioPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Helmet>
                <title>Portfolio</title>
                <meta name="title" content="Portfolio" />
                <meta name="description" content="Where Magic Happens" />

                <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
                <meta property="og:title" content="Portfolio" />
                <meta property="og:description" content="Where Magic Happens" />
                <meta property="og:image" content="/images/covers/portfolio-collaboration-default-image.jpg" />

                <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
                <meta property="twitter:title" content="Portfolio" />
                <meta property="twitter:description" content="Where Magic Happens" />
                <meta property="twitter:image" content="/images/covers/portfolio-collaboration-default-image.jpg" />
            </Helmet>
```

Appreciate any help.

**Update:**
I am publishing my website to GitHub and I have integrated GitHub with Cloudflare pages. In Cloudflare I am using this settings to build my website:

Build command:
npm run build

Build output directory:
/build

Build system version:
2 (latest)

Root directory:
/

Environment variables:
None

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in where you put `HelmetProvider`.

You're setting your meta tags in App.js which is a high level component. The `Helmet` is designed to merge all `Helmet` components found on the page. This means that if you have multiple Helmet components, all of their tags will be added to the page.

Here is how you would do it:

Set HelmetProvider in your `ReactDOM.render(...)`

```
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import App from './App';
/*Your other imports */

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HelmetProvider> {/*<---- Here*/}
      <BrowserRouter>
        <YourApp />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </HelmetProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Your `Portfolio` component looks great which wraps it with `Helmet` and similar pages.

`dynamic-meta-tags.js` isn't a correct in React. The function `Helmet.renderStatic()` is meant for server-side and not client-side. You should get rid of this file and its import from `index.html`.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I am publishing my website to GitHub and I have integrated GitHub with Cloudflare pages. In Cloudflare I am using this settings to build my website: Build command:
npm run build


Build output directory:
/build


Build system version:
2 (latest)


Root directory:
/


Environment variables:
None